# How do I show and hide dive on button click in html css trick?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have responsive Html website

I want to hide and show  on click of next in simple html

```
DEMO PAGE

Q1.WHAT IS YOUR NAME
ANS - JAMES

Q2.WHAT IS YOUR ADDRESS
ANS- PUNE
```

here Q1 and Q2 are on the same page but

I want to show only one question at a one time but do not want to create multiple physical pages.

I tried using hide and show trick of css but I want to do it on simple html button click `NEXT`

want output like following

```
Q1.WHAT IS YOUR NAME
ANS- JAMES

[CLICK NEXT]
```

it will load Q2 on same page.

I tried not using one page with different pages like below.

```
<link rel='stylesheet' type='text/css' href='css/style.css' />
<script type='text/javascript' src='http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4/jquery.min.js'></script>
    <script type='text/javascript' src='js/jquery.ba-hashchange.min.js'></script>
    <script type='text/javascript' src='js/dynamicpage.js'></script>
      <nav>
              <ul class="group">
                  <li><a href="Q1.html">Q1</a></li>
                  <li><a href="Q2.html">Q2</a></li>

              </ul>
          </nav>
<section id="main-content">
        <div id="guts">
Q1.WHAT IS YOUR NAME
ANS - JAMES
</div>
        </section>
```

Comment: Can you tell us what you've already tried?

Comment: Plus show us your HTML & CSS and a JSfiddle.

Comment: Based on click add/change attribute in the button. Create css (class) based on attribute. For reference check the html5 validation.

Comment: You're going to need to use Javascript

Comment: Check out the Jquery UI - https://jqueryui.com/accordion/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here some example with jQuery which supports more than two questions:

Try to wrap all your questions in a div and use jquery for the click event so each time you click the button a next question will appear. 
In this method you should include all your questions inside the wrapper div and set their display to none.

http://jsfiddle.net/ZFZfY/1/

Edit: http://jsfiddle.net/ZFZfY/3/

HTML:

```
  <div class="questionWrapper">
    <div class="question show" id="questionOne">
        <label>foo bar?</label>
       <input type="text">
   </div>
   <div class="question" id="questionTwo" style="display: block;">
      <label>foo bar?</label>
      <input type="text">
    </div>
  </div>
  <a class="NextQuestion" href="#">Next Question</a>
```

CSS:

```
.question{ display: none;}
.show{ display: block;}
```

jQuery:

```
$('.NextQuestion').click(function(e){
  e.preventDefault();
  loadNext();
});

$('.PrevQuestion').click(function(e){
  e.preventDefault();
  loadPrev();
});

function loadNext(){
  // loop to verify what is visible
   $('.questionWrapper').children().each(function(i){
      if($(this).css('display') === 'block' && $(this).next().length > 0){
        $(this).css('display','none');
           $(this).next().fadeIn();
        return false;
      }
    });
}

function loadPrev(){
  // loop to verify what is visible
   $('.questionWrapper').children().each(function(i){
      if($(this).css('display') === 'block' && $(this).prev().length > 0){
            $(this).css('display','none');
            $(this).prev().fadeIn();
        return false;
      }
    });
}
```

Comment: thanks but when i click next it should show only next question not previous one .. only one question .. previous will be hidden .. as for previous I have previous button

Comment: thanks I added Previous button to go back write following code but I think I miss something not working :( plz correct me
`$("#prev").click(function() {
                       $(".col:hidden:last").show("slow");
                       $('.col').prev().hide();`

Comment: Hey man, check the edited post, now you can see how to implement the previous question. I guess this isn't the best way to do that, but it works.

Answer (score 2):

Using just Javascript you can do this fairly easily. Something like this should work:

HTML

```
<label id="name">What is your name?<input type="text" /></label>
</br>
<label id="address">What is your address?<input type="text" /></label>
</br>
<button id="next">Next</button>
```

CSS

```
#address {
  display: none;
}
```

Javascript

```
document.getElementById('next').onclick=function(){
    document.getElementById('address').style.display='block';
};
```

Here is a fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/YJRbE/

Or, if you'd prefer to use jQuery, something like this:

```
$('#next').on('click', function() {
    $('#address').show();
});
```

Here is a fiddle for the jQuery version: http://jsfiddle.net/XyNXq/

Comment: thanks but it should hide first question and show current one .. same with next questions..how can i make it more dynamic?
I have around 25 questions

Comment: @ashuthinks Here is a good article on how to do that: http://rmurphey.com/blog/2008/01/08/cycle-through-list-elements-with-jquery/

Answer (score 1):

here is script

```
<script src="http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery-migrate/1.2.1/jquery-migrate.min.js"></script>

            <script type="text/javascript">


                 $(document).ready(function() {
                    $('.content').each(function() { 
                      var $this = $(this);
                      $this.find(':not(.col:first,.active)').hide();
                      $('.col').children().removeAttr('style');
                    });
                    $("#add").click(function() {
                       $(".col:hidden:first").show("slow");
                       $('.col').prev().hide();
                    });
                });
            </script>
```

here demo html

```
<div class="content">
        <div class="col">
            <h3>What Is Your Name</h3>
            <input type="text">
        </div>
        <div class="col">
            <h3>What Is Address</h3>
            <input type="text">
        </div>
        <button id="add" class="active">Add</button>
    </div>
```

Comment: working gud for many questions :) But I want to hide previous question when New question comes in.. there should be only one question is visible at a one time.. plz modify answer

Comment: thanks I added Previous button to go back write following code but I think I miss something not working :( plz correct me $("#prev").click(function() {                        $(".col:hidden:last").show("slow");                        $('.col').prev().hide();

Answer (score 0):

Hope this helps.

You can change the visibility of elements on button click like this.

```
document.getElementById('name').style.display='none';
document.getElementById('address').style.display='block';
```

Here is the [working demo](http://jsfiddle.net/9Rh7M/)